# Python Reading from .txt file

Tags: python

So the basic concept of what I am trying to create is something that searches through a .txt file and finds the highest scorer of the game and combine his score for all the levels he played. More information:
The .txt file I have is in the following format:

```
Username:level:Score
Starplayer:2:24
John:2:14
Starplayer:3:14
```

Above for example the highest scorer would be Starplayer with a score of 38 points since it is both scores combined. Here is what I have gotten so far:

```
search = input("Enter the player name you want to search up for: ")
print("\nThe level scores for ",search," are:\nGame Level      Score:")
searchfile = open("playerScores.txt", "r")
for line in searchfile:
    if search in line: print("Level: ",(line.split(",")[1]),"           Score: ",(line.split(",")[2]))
searchfile.close()
```

The above finds the name of a sepcific player in the .txt file and tells you their score. Now maybe that could be combined with some extra code to find all the scores in a for loop and not stop until it finds the highest one. I am not 100% how to do it myself though so I am here asking for help.
Thanks you SO much if you got any suggestions :)

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to do. Are you looking for the highest scorer, or are you looking for the result of the player you got the name of in your input?

Comment: Looks like you are also the one that is *creating* this score file. Why not use a better data structure? You could use a CSV, or SQLITE, or even pickle to save your scores.

Comment: @InbarRose It looks like he already is using a CSV. But I agree that a database (whether SQL or dbm/shelve or otherwise) would make things a whole lot easier.

Comment: @DaphnaShezaf Sorry if it was a bit unclear, im looking for the Highest-scorer of all combined levels. Thank for asking

Comment: Anyway, you need to accumulate the total running score for each player. That either means using a dictionary (or something equivalent and harder, like a custom tree-based mapping...), or reading over the whole file N times instead of once.

Answer (score 3):

It's a lot easier to use dictionaries here

```
players = {}
with open("playerScores.txt", "r") as searchfile:
    searchfile.readline() # skip headers
    for line in searchfile:
        line = line.rstrip().split(":")
        if line[0] in players:
            players[line[0]] += int(line[2])
        else:
            players[line[0]] = int(line[2])
players = [[v,k] for k,v in players.items()]
players.sort(reverse=True)
# players is now in order of highest scoring players with it [score,name] for each element
```

The reason to use dictionaries is it makes it A LOT easier to keep track of seen players (as you can just the name as a key in a dictionary and it points to a score value).

However, you can do this with just lists if you really wanted. This just requires having to iterate through our list till we find the right player to add the score too. It's functionally equivalent to the above, but it's slower.

```
players = []
with open("playerScores.txt", "r") as searchfile:
    searchfile.readline() # skip headers
    for line in searchfile:
        line = line.rstrip().split(":")
        found = False
        for i in range(len(players)):
            if players[i][1] == line[0]:
                players[i][0] += int(line[2])
                found = True
        if not found:
            players.append([int(line[2]),line[0]])
players.sort(reverse=True)
```

Both answers give you a list of lists of the form `[[top-score, player], [second-score, player],...]`

As mentioned in the comments, if you're only interested in the top player (and no others), instead of sorting, you could just use `max(players)` and that'll return the top `[score, player]` pair.

Comment: Good answer, but you don't need to decorate-and-sort; you can just use a key: `players = sorted(players.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)` or similar.

Comment: Or you could just use `max` instead of sorting (or `heapq.nlargest` if he wants the top 10 instead of the top 1).

Comment: you did not consider `Username:level:Score` in the playerScores.txt. If you leave that out of consideration, both work nice!

Answer (score 2):

I too am a big fan of dictionaries in python. you loop over the file, adding every player to a dictionary if it is not already in there. if it is in there you just combine the score that is already in with the score from the line you read.

```
score_dictionary = {}

with open('scorefile.txt') as handle:
    for line in handle:
        line = line.rstrip()
        name = line.split(":")[0]
        score = int(line.split(":")[2])

        if name not in list(score_dictionary):
            score_dictionary[name] = score
        else:
            score_dictionary[name] = score_dictionary[name] + score

values = list(score_dictionary.values())
keys = list(score_dictionary.keys())
print keys[values.index(max(values))], max(values)
```

In this case you should rewrite your score file so it does no longer contain the header and it looks like this:

```
Starplayer:2:24
John:2:14
Starplayer:3:14
```

this script will give the following output:

```
Starplayer 38
```